# Spatie Media Library - Array to string conversion

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-medialibrary

I am trying to get `Spatie Media Library` to work, but I have this error:
[image: Error]

I really don't know where it comes from, any suggestions?

I'll leave a copy of the portion of the code where the error happens

##### `Str.php`

```
/**
 * Replace the given value in the given string.
 *
 * @param  string|string[]  $search
 * @param  string|string[]  $replace
 * @param  string|string[]  $subject
 * @return string
 */
public static function replaceArray($search, array $replace, $subject)
{
    $segments = explode($search, $subject);

    $result = array_shift($segments);

    foreach ($segments as $segment) {
        $result .= (array_shift($replace) ?? $search).$segment;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Check the stack trace on the left, if you see any file that is custom from you, share that stack trace (click on it and see what code is triggering it), if it is not, check what middleware could be triggering code from the library you are using and share it here please

Comment: Pls share the complete stacktrace share the error via flare.

Comment: Thanks guys, I was able to fix it now. During the day I will upload the answer in case it helps someone

Comment: Where's the solution?

Comment: Where's the solution?